# Firebase not logging in when using Facebook, works fine on Google

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this code for signing in using Facebook on Firebase:

```
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    final LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            SignUp.this.startActivity(startMainActivity);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Login has been cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.w("FBSA", "Error logging in: " + error.getMessage());
            createDialogSignUpError();
        }
    });
```

**onActivityResult:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        Log.d("AD", "Signed in via google successfully:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            Toast.makeText(this, "An error has occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**handleFacebookAccessToken:**

```
private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d("FBSA", "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d("FBSA", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w("FBSA", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

But, the user is not logging in. `onError` is not getting called, and `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` returns `null`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you add `mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` in your `onActivityResult` method?

Comment: @MdSufiKhan forgot about those and the other method, will include

Comment: @MdSufiKhan's answer should do the job.

Comment: @MdSufiKhan I already have that

Comment: Have you enabled facebook in firebase consloe authentication???

Comment: @NarenderReddy yes

Comment: Do you get an error about the key hash? another error?

Comment: One word: LOGS. onComplete in signInWithCredential should print something. Change `Log.w("FBSA", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());` to `Log.wtf("FBSA"....`, this will highlight exception with red color. Then add it to post

Comment: @DimaRostopira It seems like `onComplete` isn't getting called

Comment: @AbAppletic if it is not calling - then whole method handleFacebookAccessToken not called too. Have you initialized. So at least one of methods in loginButtonCallback must be called. Add more logging or use breakpoints

Comment: @DimaRostopira the method gets called, but `onComplete` doesn't

Comment: @AbAppletic are you sure, it isn't called? Check your logcat filter, set it to Warning, it's probably set to Error

Comment: @DimaRostopira I debugged it...

Comment: if any of the button callback methods not called too - then I don't know what you are doing wrong. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I turned Facebook off in the Firebase Console, then I turn it back on. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to log in with the same user using 2 different ways. I get this exception message if I try to login with a Facebook account that has the email of a previously registered user (with email and password) in my firebase project.

```
"An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address."
```

Comment: I already solved it in a different way, but +1 since it is useful for future reasons

Answer (score -2):

This is a working code, I added the code I don't see in your question:

In onCreate add:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplication());
```

In onSuccess call RequestData() method:

```
 login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                    RequestData();

                    handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                }
            }


ProfilePictureView profile;

public void RequestData() {

    Log.v(TAG, "RequestData");

    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
            try {
                if (json != null) {
                    String text = "<b>Name :</b> " + json.getString("name") + "<br><br><b>Email :</b> " + json.getString("email") + "<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> " + json.getString("link");

                    Log.d(TAG, "facush:" + text);

                    profile.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: What is requestData(), why do I need it? What's all that code in there? Why didn't firebase mention it? Clear your answer

Comment: You downvote instead of checking?... a real motivation to help you. Anyway, it's from Facebook developers site.

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't explain ANYTHING. Whats that "ProfilePictureView"? There is so much unnecessary code that Firebase doesn't open its mouth about.

Comment: Firebase has a link to Facebook site about implementing the login button -they start with "Integrate Facebook Login into your app by following the developer's documentation".

Comment: Indeed it does, however nothing with that huge code is there.

Comment: Did you try to add "FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());" to your onCreate method?